# Script bash that tail always a logfile and when match particular word, send mail

Tags: bash, sendmail, logfile

I have searched in all threads but I don't know how to solve my very simple problem..

I think is very simple but I'm not a bash expert..

I need a bash script that executes a continuous tail in a logfile and when grep the word "fail", execute another command and send me a mail (but the tail command must not stop)

I think I need for a "for loop" or "while read" or "if then else" commands. I tried different ways but couldn't find a working script..

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, it is simpler and better to use standard Linux utilities, instead of implementing this functionality with bash:

```
tail -f log-file | stdbuf -oL grep fail | xargs -L1 send-mail-alert
```

You have already figured out that you need tail/grep. You need two additional ingredients: stdbuf and xargs

The stdbuf will force 'line buffering', resulting in the 'fail' messages sent to the 'xargs' program without (buffering) delay.

The 'xargs' command will activate the script 'send-mail-alert' on every occurrence of 'fail'. You can inline the mail delivery, and use a script